# Can not use `cut -c` (`--characters`) with UTF-8?

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, unicode, cut

The command `cut` has an option `-c` to work on characters, instead of bytes with the option `-b`. But that does not seem to work, in `en_US.UTF-8` locale:

The second byte gives the second ASCII character (which is encoded just the same in UTF-8):

```
$ printf 'ABC' | cut -b 2          
B
```

but does not give the second of three greek non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 locale:

```
$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -b 2         
�
```

That's alright - it's the second **byte**.
So we look at the second **character** instead:

```
$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -c 2 
�
```

That looks broken.
With some experiments, it turns out that the range `3-4` shows the second character:

```
$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -c 3-4
β
```

But that's just the same as the bytes 3 to 4:

```
$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -b 3-4
β
```

So the `-c` does not more than the `-b` for UTF-8.

I'd expect the locale setup is not right for UTF-8, but in comparison, `wc` works as expected;
It is often used to count bytes, with option `-c` (`--bytes`). 
 <sup>(Note the confusing option names.)</sup>

```
$ printf 'αβγ' | wc -c
6
```

But it can also count characters with option `-m` (`--chars`), which just works:

```
$ printf 'αβγ' | wc -m
3
```

So my configuration seems to be ok - but something is special about `cut`.

Maybe it does not support UTF-8 at all? But it does seem to support multi-byte characters, otherwise it would not need to support `-b` and `-c`.

**So, what's wrong? And why?**

The locale setup looks right for utf8, as far as I can tell:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The input, byte by byte:

```
$ printf 'αβγ' | hd 
00000000  ce b1 ce b2 ce b3                                 |......|
00000006
```

Comment: Interesting! It looks like `-c` is using the same code as `-b`. Did you have a look at the source code? Maybe you can find a hint what `-c` is actually meant for.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You haven't said which `cut` you're using, but since you've mentioned the GNU long option `--characters` I'll assume it's that one. In that case, note this [passage from `info coreutils 'cut invocation'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html):

> ```
> ‘-c character-list’
> ‘--characters=character-list’
> ```
>
> Select for printing only the characters in positions listed in character-list. **The same as `-b` for now**, but internationalization will change that.

(emphasis added)

For the moment, GNU `cut` always works in terms of single-byte "characters", so the behaviour you see is expected.

---

Supporting both the `-b` and `-c` options is [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) — they weren't added to GNU `cut` because it had multi-byte support and they worked properly, but to avoid giving errors on POSIX-compliant input. The same `-c` has been done in some other `cut` implementations, although not [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cut&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%209.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)'s and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cut.1.html)'s at least.

This is the [historic behaviour](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html#tag_20_28_16) of `-c`. `-b` was newly added to take over the byte role so that `-c` can work with multi-byte characters. Maybe in a few years it will work as desired consistently, although progress hasn't exactly been quick (it's been over a decade already). GNU `cut` [doesn't even implement the `-n` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cut-invocation.html#index-g_t_002dn-669) yet, even though it is orthogonal and intended to help the transition. There are potential compatibility problems with old scripts, which may be a concern, although I don't know definitively what the reason is.

Comment: good work. youll find the same kind of comments in GNU's `tr` docs as well. and even `tar` unless i misremember. i guess its a big project.

Comment: Is there any workaround for unicode probelm in `cut`? For example, where is it possible to download the sources for patched `cut`? Or would it be more easier to use another utility? (`grep` solution below does not work smoothly with ranges e.g. `5-8,44-49`)

Comment: see this 2017 article, sub-titled *”Random notes and pointers regarding the on-going effort to add multibyte and unicode support in GNU Coreutils“*: https://crashcourse.housegordon.org/coreutils-multibyte-support.html

Comment: you can find some alternatives to `cut -c` here: https://superuser.com/questions/506164/using-grep-to-display-second-character-in-string

Answer (score 13):

`colrm` (part of `util-linux`, should be already installed on most distributions) seems to handle internationalization much better :

```
$ echo 'αβγ' | colrm 3
αβ
$ echo 'αβγ' | colrm 2
α
```

Beware of the numbering : `colrm N` will remove columns from `N`, printing characters up to `N-1`.

([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6213244/812102))

Comment: colrm doesn't seem to handle emojis well: `echo 'removethis' | colrm 2` returns nothing for me.

Comment: @frabjous They seem to count for two characters, try `echo 'removethis' | colrm 3`. ;)

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou no that's wrong. UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are just different encodings of Unicode, and all can [represent characters up to U+10FFFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52203351/995714). Characters outside the BMP are represented by 4 bytes in both UTF-8 and UTF-16

Comment: @phuclv Right, comment removed.  Please keep yours as it’s informative (hopefully readers will understand it refers to a deleted comment and not to the answer…).

Answer (score 7):

Since many `grep` implementations are multibyte-aware, you can also use `grep -o` to simulate some uses of `cut -c`.

First two characters:

```
$ echo Τηεοδ29 | grep -o '^..'
Τη
```

Last three characters:

```
$ echo Τηεοδ29 | grep -o '...$'
δ29
```

Second character:

```
$ echo Τηεοδ29 | grep -o '^..' | grep -o '.$'
η
```

Adjust the number of periods, or use `{x,y}` syntax, to simulate `cut` ranges.

Comment: no need for such complex solutions to get the second character. `echo Τηεοδ29 | grep -Po '(?<=^.).'` or `echo Τηεοδ29 | grep -Po '^.\K.'` will suffice

Comment: @phuclv Very cool - though I'd argue that it's trading one form of complexity for another, it's definitely a big improvement for many use cases!

Answer (score 2):

*Eight+ years later, I can't reproduce the OP's issue (MacOS 13.4 Ventura):*

```
~$ printf 'ABC' | cut -b 2
B
~$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -b 2
�
~$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -c 2
β
~$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -c 3-4
γ
~$ printf 'αβγ' | cut -b 3-4
β
~$ printf 'αβγ' | wc -c
       6
~$ printf 'αβγ' | wc -m
       3
```

Above seems to be the answer the OP was hoping for? Note the line ending `cut -c 3-4` actually returns `γ%` under `zsh`, indicating a partial line (more characters requested than could be returned).

`-$ man cut` doesn't give me a version other than `macOS 13.4 August 3, 2017`, IEEE Std 1003.2-1992 (“POSIX.2”), with an additional `-w` flag as an extension to the specification. *"HISTORY: A cut command appeared in AT&T System III UNIX."*