# How to truncate text lines to N characters maximum?

Tags: text-processing, cut

Given a text file, or the output of a command, how can I truncate it so that every line longer than `N` characters (usually `N=80` in a terminal) gets shorten to `N` characters maximum?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175852

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) to achieve this (using `N=80` here):

```
some-command | cut -c -80
```

or

```
cut -c -80 some-file.txt
```

Replace 80 with the number of characters you want to keep.

Note that:

- Multi-bytes characters may not be handled correctly, depending on your implementation;
- Multi-characters bytes (aka tabs) may be treated as one char (& [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175852/what-commands-will-feed-a-tab-delimited-text-file-and-cut-each-line-to-80-char) treats this).

---

*Dale Anderson* suggests the use of `some-command | cut -c -$COLUMNS` which truncates to the current terminal width.

*Libin Wen* suggests that the equivalent `cut -c 1-80` may be better for understanding.

Comment: The equivalent form `cut -c 1-80` may be better for understanding.

Comment: fixed command syntax you must supply a range: "some-command | cut -c *1-80*"

Comment: Without the `1` it's easy to miss the `-` before the 80 so I agree it makes more sense.

Comment: I like to use `some-command | cut -c -$COLUMNS` which uses the entire terminal width, whatever that currently happens to be.

Comment: How to keep color from `some-command`?

Comment: @Kindred usually, `some-command` detect their output type (terminal, pipe, file...), and thus automatically disable colouring when their output is not going to a terminal. There is usually an option to force coloured output. For example, `grep --color=always` (same for `ls`). Look at the `man` for `your-command`. Note that your version of `cut` however, may not consider the extra colouring bytes as zero sized characters, and may therefore cut a text with and without colour differently.

Comment: Using `... cut -c -${SOME_NUMBER} ...` may result in invalid strings, as for example with emojis (which are multibyte characters).
Example: Using `` (with each of these emoji smiley being a 4-byte character): `echo '' | cut -b -7 | xargs touch` creates a file named `''$'\360\237\230'`, that is: the first four bytes are correctly interpreted as the *Smiling Face with Sunglasses*, while the remaining three bytes result in an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

Comment: Exacerbatingly, even in 2023, *GNU coreutils 9.3's cut* still doesn't handle UTF-8 right, as it assumes a "character" to always be "one byte" in size (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163725/20230), so `cut -c` behaves effectively like `cut -b` ("b" for "byte").
To get rid of any invalid trailing bytes, the string can be piped through `iconv -c -t UTF-8`: `echo '' | cut -b -7 | iconv -c -t UTF-8 | xargs touch` creates a file named ``, while `echo '' | cut -b -8 | iconv -c -t UTF-8 | xargs touch` (one more byte) results in a file ``.