# awk, cut characters out of substring

Tags: awk, sed, date, csv

I have the following csv. I'm trying to remove the 20 out of 2017 so it's formatted like 3717 or 31817. The positions are always different due to some dates having single digit days. Since the year is always 4 digits how can I remove the 20 from the second column going right to left?

```
12  322017   EODTRANSACTION J    87.75   
12  3232017  EODTRANSACTION J    155  
45  3302017  EODTRANSACTION J    270
```

Expected Output

```
12  3217    EODTRANSACTION J    87.75   
12  32317   EODTRANSACTION J    155  
45  33017   EODTRANSACTION J    270
```

Comment: does the 2nd column always end with 2017? no other year possible in data you have?

Comment: The years will change

Comment: Try awk along with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163481/a-command-to-print-only-last-3-characters-of-a-string

Comment: Why do people insist on using stupid date formats? What is wrong with `20170412`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{match($2, /^([0-9]+)[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})$/, a); $2=a[1]a[2]}1' file
```

The output:

```
12 3217 EODTRANSACTION J 87.75
12 32317 EODTRANSACTION J 155
45 33017 EODTRANSACTION J 270
```

---

`match($2, /^([0-9]+)[0-9]{2}([0-9]{2})$/, a)` - will capture all digits from the second field except the **3**rd and **4**th digit at the end

Answer (score 0):

Replace the second field with the result of: substituting the first "20" in the second field with the empty string, then print the resulting line:

```
awk '{$2=gensub("20", "", 1, $2); print;}' input > output
```